# Tagged and Untagged Cisco vLAN port

Tags: cisco, vlan

I have a whole bunch of Dell switches I support and most of our users have a VOIP phone on vLAN 999 and a PC on a couple of vLANs. On the Dell switches I simply set the PC's vlan to untagged and then the Phone's vLAN to tagged - both connected to the same port on the switch (socket on wall to phone, socket on phone to PC) and it all works.

Last year a Cisco 2960S switch was installed in a new extension and I setup the required PC vlans on them, no VOIP phones were used in that office .... until today. How can I setup a single port on the switch to essentially do what the Dell switches already do ie Untagged for the PC for, in this case vLAN 14 (which is already setup on that switch in vlans), and tagged for the VOIP phones on vLAN 999.

No 'Voice LAN' has been setup on the network ... just set them all up on vLAN 999, which is configured on all the switches and across various trunks.

Answer (score 0):

So, i understood that you configured your Switchports with "switchport access vlan 14" already
if your phones are supporting CDP or LLDP, and i suppose they are supporting at least LLDP, you can configure a "switchport voice vlan 999" on the specified interface.
This command causes that VLAN Tag 999 is sigaled to the phones, and the phones are tagging their traffic with the specified Dot1q tag.

I hope this solves your Problem

regards
Andreas